# Can I copy a file to two drives at the same time from a single read? (Copy one-to-two in single operation, preferably in rsync)

Tags: hard-drive, files, backup, rsync, archive

I frequently need to back up a source disk to multiple target disks. At the moment the workflow is `rsync` from *source* to *target1* then `dd` clone *target1* to *target2*.

It would be lovely if I could `rsync` from *source* to *target1*+*target2* sequentially in the same read operation to greatly speed things up. Read the file into memory one time and write it to two separate hard drives in grand synchrony.

Is there perhaps a way to have `rsync` read the file into memory and  pipe the output to two write operations simultaneously? Doesn't *have* to be `rsync` but that'd be greatly preferred.

Comment: I think what you want happens already in current versions of Ubuntu, if there is enough free RAM for the whole file or the whole batch of files that rsync or some other tool is to copy. (But a huge file or batch of files might not fit into RAM). I have noticed that when I create USB boot drives from an iso file, the second time the read process needs almost no time (but of course the write process will still be limited by the write speed of each target device).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting together info from several sources, there are a few options.

**The conclusion is that only with [command `parallel`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man1/parallel.1.html) you might get what you want, see below.**

Important notes:

1. I have made tests with `cp` for copying. You should also consider speedups (or down!) obtained with `rsync` vs `cp` or other alternative commands, combined with `parallel`.
2. I have tested copying only one file. Results might change if copying many files (e.g., combining a few large files, as you need, with many other small files and subdirectories).

---

For each of the options, I have tested both

```
time <option #N, copying to one target>
time <option #N, copying to two targets>
```

to get a comparison, with a file of 1.2Gb.
Moreover, in some cases I tested two or three times the same command, to assess the dispersion in the results.
I did not compute averages and standard deviations, but the results are obvious.

This is what I got under the testing conditions specified above, with brief comments.
I have concatenated in a single row the results of multiple tests, whenever available.

**The *base case***:

```
$ time cp -p source/file1 target1/

real    0m0,846s    0m0,680s    0m0,659s
user    0m0,000s    0m0,001s    0m0,016s
sys     0m0,777s    0m0,662s    0m0,643s
```

**The *copying options***:

1. *Option* `parallel`

   ```
   $ parallel cp -p source/file1 ::: target1/
   real    0m0,745s    0m0,740s
   user    0m0,121s    0m0,108s
   sys     0m0,609s    0m0,619s

   $ parallel cp -p source/file1 ::: target1/ target2/
   real    0m0,794s    0m0,860s
   user    0m0,116s    0m0,134s
   sys     0m1,300s    0m1,380s
   ```
2. *Option* `tee` (appending  `> /dev/null` to avoid output to `stdout`)

   ```
   $ tee target1/file1 < source/file1 > /dev/null
   real    0m0,874s    0m1,040s    0m1,028s
   user    0m0,160s    0m0,172s    0m0,137s
   sys     0m0,714s    0m0,868s    0m0,887s

   $ tee target1/file1 target2/file1 < source/file1 > /dev/null
   real    0m1,802s    0m1,680s    0m1,833s
   user    0m0,136s    0m0,212s    0m0,197s
   sys     0m1,642s    0m1,468s    0m1,619s
   ```

   Copying to two `target`s roughly doubles the time for one `target`, which is slightly larger than the time for the *base case*.
3. *Option* `xargs`

   ```
   $ echo target1 | xargs -n 1 cp -p source/file1
   real    0m0,666s
   user    0m0,021s
   sys     0m0,646s

   $ echo target1 target2 | xargs -n 1 cp -p source/file1
   real    0m1,197s
   user    0m0,018s
   sys     0m1,173s
   ```

   Copying to two `target`s roughly doubles the time for one `target`, which is similar to the time for the *base case*.
4. *Option* `find`

   ```
   $ find target1 -exec cp -p source/file1 {} \;
   real    0m2,167s
   user    0m0,017s
   sys     0m1,627s

   $ find target1 target2 -exec cp -p source/file1 {} \;
   real    0m3,905s
   user    0m0,020s
   sys     0m3,185s
   ```

   Copying to two `target`s roughly doubles the time for one `target`, which is much larger than the time for the *base case*... a clear loser.

**Sources for "multiple copying"**:

1. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-copy-a-file-to-multiple-directories-using-cp-command/
2. [How to copy a file to multiple folders using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432795/how-to-copy-a-file-to-multiple-folders-using-the-command-line)
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195655/how-to-copy-a-file-to-multiple-directories-using-the-gnu-cp-command

**Sources for performance `cp` vs. `rsync`**:

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91382/rsync-is-very-slow-factor-8-to-10-compared-to-cp-on-copying-files-from-nfs-sha
2. https://lwn.net/Articles/400489/
3. https://superuser.com/questions/1170636/why-is-there-a-write-speed-difference-between-dd-cp-rsync-and-macos-finder-to
4. [What's the difference between ` cp ` and ` rsync `?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806371/whats-the-difference-between-cp-and-rsync)

Comment: Have you checked the time used (with fairly big files) to verify that your examples really avoid re-reading the source file, or otherwise improve the speed compared to 'copying twice'?

Comment: @sudodus - You are correct, will shortly refine this point.

Comment: Let me guess: the example with parallel will be best (or at least one of the best).

Comment: @sudodus - `parallel` seems to be not only the best, but the only one to achieve the target.

Answer (score 3):

`rsync` has a *batch mode* you could experiment with. When you do an `rsync --write-batch=foo from to` it will do the usual copying, but also replicate the instructions and data into file `foo`. If instead of a file this is a fifo you can use a second rsync in parallel to read the fifo and do a new rsync to a different destination. Obviously, the new destination must be sufficiently similar to the original to make sense.

For example, over a network you might try

```bsh
mkfifo myfifo
ssh remotec 'rsync -av --read-batch=- destc' <myfifo &
sleep 1
rsync -av --write-batch=myfifo srca/ remoteb:destb
```

`--read-batch` cannot be used with a `remote:destc` style destination.